# How do I avoid cross-origin issues when requesting data from a sub-domain?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cross-domain, cloudflare

On my site www.example.com, I submit an ajax request to a sub-domain:

```
function submit(json_data) {
  return $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "https://sub-domain.example.com",
     data: json_data
  });
}
```

https://sub-domain.example.com points to a different IP address (on Amazon ec2) than example.com. This all used to work fine. However, when I changed example.com to HTTPS only, I started getting errors such as the following:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sub-domain.example.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 522.

I use Cloudflare. What's a simple way to fix this error?

- Can I change a setting in Cloudflare so there's no issue? I thought of setting up a page at example.com/sub-domain that pointed to the same IP address as before, but this didn't seem possible.
- Is there a simple change I can do to the request? I tried using jsonp, but that didn't work with POST.
- If that's not possible, how do I change the actual sub-domain to allow such requests from example.com?

Comment: It seems like you're going to have to set-up the CORS headers on Cloudflare. [This blog post](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203063414-Why-can-t-I-see-my-CORS-headers-) may be of some help

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable cors requests on your subdomain and comes by allowing the domain *www.example.com* to issues requests to your sub-domain.

[Check this page](http://enable-cors.org/) maybe it will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'`

to the application.rb and restarting the app server.

Comment: I could add this to example.com? Since sub-domain.example.com isn't a Rails app.

Comment: Put it on the app making the request.  I believe it appends that header to all the responses received by the app.

Comment: You need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header sent by the domain that the request is going to, in your case `sub-domain.example.com`. This is to prevent people from making requests to your server from unauthorized domains.